# Rails model callback when has_and_belongs_to_many association has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, callback

I’m trying to fire an `after_save` callback on my `Job` model only when it has a `Surveyor` added or changed on it (given that one is also present too).

```
# app/models/job.rb 
has_and_belongs_to_many :surveyors
after_save :send_mail, if: ->(r) { r.surveyor_ids_changed? and r.surveyor_ids.present? }

# app/models/surveyor.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs

# permitted parameters on job
:job_name, :job_address, surveyor_ids: []
```

How might I change the model callback to get the `send_mail` method firing properly?

Comment: `r.surveyor_ids.present?` why you need to check it? in `after_save` as it will create a persisted instance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean you can use callback to your surveyor model using `after_update` and check it `changed?`

Answer (score 0):

`#changed?` will always be false after saving the model, but you can use [`#previous_changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) to do the thing